# Why is Forfiles recursing even though I'm not using the /S parameter?

Tags: windows, batch-file, forfiles

In my Windows batch file on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, I'm trying to use the Forfiles command without recursing through my files, but it still recurses even though I am not using the /S parameter.

How can I get it to stop recursing

I've tried it with both @path and @file and even with the /s.  When I use the /S, the amount of recursion is ridiculous!

```
ForFiles /p "C:\temp" /d -30 /c "cmd /c dir @path" >temp.txt
```

In the code above, I expect the temp.txt to only show files in the specified folder, not any of it's subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider what you are asking the system to do:

```
Forfiles /p "C:\temp" /d -30
```

The above command does pretty much what you intended, find any file/folder older than 30 days.

```
/c "cmd /c dir @path"
```

This does not do what you think. You are effectively asking `cmd` to `dir` each match found by `forfiles` and do the full dir of each `@path`, including folders. So let's say you have a dir older than 30 days:

```
C:\Temp\oldInstalldir\
```

You are telling `cmd.exe` to do:

```
dir "C:\Temp\oldinstalldir"
```

as well as dir for each file in `c:\temp` again. So what you really want is to list the files you found older than 30 days which `forfiles` already found for you, so a working solution is to just `echo` them.

```
ForFiles /p "C:\temp" /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path">temp.txt
```

Or by filename only (no path):

```
ForFiles /p "C:\temp" /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @file">temp.txt
```

Comment: That worked!  And it let me accomplish my end goal which is to delete all files more than 30 days old:
ForFiles /p "C:\temp2" /d -30 /c "cmd /c del /F /Q @file">temp.txt

TYVM!

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary solution you could try.  It is kinda hacky but it might work for what you are trying to do.

Add `/M "\*.\*"` to your command and it will skip the directories unless they have `.` in the name which most usually do not.  I didn't see it recursing the subdirectories but there was no way to mask the directories with that command.  I tried a few attempts using

```
dir /b /a-d
```

This gets a list of all the not directories but I couldn't pipe the rusults into the forfiles command to get it to use that as the input to do the date masking. Sorry for the
partial solution.

Comment: No, this is not a solution, in fact it is horrible advice to give OP. The problem is not with `forfiles`, it is the fact that OP is doing a `dir` on each match of `@path` including directories... `dir "C:\temp\someDIR` So the correct aswer would be is NOT to use `dir` at all. `forfiles` effectively did the filtered `dir` already.

Comment: This won't work as we do have directories with the "." in the name

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't consider dropping the "dir" since it was part of the request but it makes sense why it must be dropped.  Thank you for the real solution (I learned something new today:)